# make a list inside of a list using loops

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a function that returns a list of n elements like the following:

```
factorial_list(4) → [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

my output is `[[1], [1], [2], [1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3], [4]]` 
As you see I'm struggling to make the order of the inner lists. Any insights to what I should change in my code?

```
def factorial_list(n):
    list2=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            list2.append([j])
    print(list2)

factorial_list(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Method 1:** based on the logic of your code

```
def factorial_list(n):
    final_list = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        temp = []
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            temp.append(j)
        final_list.append(temp)
    print(final_list)

factorial_list(4)   # [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

> **Method 2:** a mix of *for loop* and *list comprehensions*

```
def factorial_list(n):
    final_list = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        temp = [j for j in range(1, i+1)]
        final_list.append(temp)
    print(final_list)

factorial_list(4)  # [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

> **Method 3:** using *list comprehensions*

```
def factorial_list(n):
    final_list = [[j for j in range(1, i+1)] for i in range(1, n+1)]
    print(final_list)

factorial_list(4)   # [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: At first, list comprehensions can be confusing, but after a bit of practice they become easier to read and understand quickly than a loop.  Method 3 is what most of us would say is the most "pythonic" answer.  Thanks for providing the stepwise revision helping to make the nested comprehension clear!  Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new list for each iteration of the first loop:

```py
def factorial_list(n):
    list2=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list3 = []  # <--- Create a new list for each iteration

        for j in range(1,i+1):
            list3.append(j)
        list2.append(list3)

    print(list2)

factorial_list(4)

# Output: [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```